# An algorithm to compute a set of states that satisfy a specific CTL formula

Tags: algorithms, model-checking, computation-tree-logic

Working through a past exam question and I'm unsure where to start or what form they want the answer in:

*Define an algorithm that receives as input a finite transition
system TS defined over the set of actions {a, b, c} and computes 
the set of states of TS that satisfy the CTL formula ∃a U b.*

Would anybody be able to give me a kick-start or a walk-through on how to answer this? Really appreciate any help.

edit: My attempt based on Klaus' answer

```
for all executions in TS
 for all states
  if **b** holds 
   add current state to the stack, EXISTS = TRUE
  else if **a** holds
   if current state == next state in execution 
    do nothing
   else if next state contains **a** or **b** 
    add current state to the stack, EXISTS = TRUE
   else 
    do nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

The set of states satisfying $\exists a U b$ is the smallest set $S$ such that

- $S$ contains all states satisfying $b$, and
- $S$ contains all states satisfying $a$ which have a successor in $S$

Note that we specify the "smallest" such set because otherwise you could  pick the set of all states, or include arbitrary cycles of $a$-states, etc. Do you see how to get an algorithm from this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I posted my attempt as an edit of the original post - didn't take the EXISTS operator into consideration (yet) but do I have the right idea?

Comment: One problem with the current approach is the notion of the "last state" - transition systems usually contain cycles.

Comment: OK. I made further changes and also tried to include ∃, not confident that it works though

Comment: Approaching the problem in terms of executions is probably misleading - try to construct the set of states backwards, starting from the states satisfying $b$.